# Expansion of functional in power terms

Tags: calculus-of-variations

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kT1M0.png

I'm really lost as to what to do. Do I need to Taylor expand around $\alpha=0$? And if so, how does the third expansion term even look like? I found the first and second terms to:

$$J_0=\int_{x_1}^{x_2}f(y,y_x,x)dx$$

$$J_1=\int_{x_1}^{x_2}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial \alpha}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y_x}\frac{\partial y_x}{\partial \alpha}dx$$

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: integration by parts over variable 'x' and you get it

Comment: How exactly? I'm afraid I'm a bit stumped by this variational calculus